# Reduce tags usage with low follower / question ratio (widget names and ubiquitous CS words)

Tags: discussion, tags

Tags have the [purpose of channelling questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) to experts able and willing to answer them.

In the most used tags, you can find these statistics:

```
 [function]   885 followers, 62k questions
 [class]      728 followers, 51.7k questions 
 [loops]      750 followers, 51.2k questions 
 [date]       274 followers, 48.2k questions
 [session]    373 followers, 37.5k questions 
 [object]     893 followers, 37.2k questions
 [dictionary] 324 followers, 36.4k questions 
 [variables]  235 followers, 37.3k questions
 [button]     149 followers, 28.5k questions
 [checkbox]    74 followers, 23.2k questions
 [text]       350 followers, 21.9k questions 
 [methods]    323 followers, 21.2k questions 
 [replace]     78 followers, 17.9k questions 
 [printing]   211 followers, 17k questions 
 [scroll]     211 followers, 17k questions 
 [types]      272 followers, 16.4k questions
 [build]      431 followers, 14.5k questions 
 [menu]        44 followers, 13.1k questions
 [path]        88 followers, 12.4k questions 
 [pagination]  69 followers, 12.3k questions
 [static]     172 followers, 12.2k questions
 [background]  65 followers, 11.8k questions 
 [notifications] 88 followers, 11.6k questions
 [tabs]        41 followers, 11.6k questions
 [null]       109 followers, 11.3k questions
 [routes]      88 followers, 11k questions
 [textbox]     48 followers, 10.6k questions 
 [installation] 148 followers, 10.5k questions
 [onclick]     56 followers, 10.3k questions 
 [dialog]      57 followers, 9.8k questions
 [iterator]    96 followers, 9.4k questions
 [tags]       130 followers, 8.6k questions
```

Those are not concepts that anyone can be an expert in. Or would anyone put 'I am a subject matter expert on checkboxes and loops' in their CV?

These tags seem to be abused, in that people actually tag their questions a lot by them, but hardly anyone uses them as favorites, meaning they do not contribute to the purpose of tags. (I assume nobody uses them to exclude questions neither, not sure about those statistics).

I guess that questions using those tags would also have those in the title, because they become meaningful in a full sentence, and thus having them in the title only would be better than adding a tag.

What's worse, since most humans will stop adding tags to a question when 'it feels enough', these tags eat up slots that ought to be used by more meaningful tags.

Other than burning these tags, users could at least be discouraged more strongly from using them (since using them brings no benefit to anyone), such as colouring them somehow or otherwise indicating that while they are popular, using them will not increase the chances of a question reaching the right expert. (Unless somebody chooses to ignore those to filter out questions written with poor quality.

While there may be many other such tags that are not helpful, I believe removing the most-used unhelpful tags could increase the usage of more helpful tags and thus improve the rate at which the right experts get suitable questions delivered.

As a side-note, it may also make sense for Stack Overflow to handle programming language tags specially. They seem very much like meta-tags in many respects, most questions need one and only one such language, and they also eat away a (psychological) slot for a more useful tag about the question.

### title / tag examples:

- [Reducing loop/recursion time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604564/reducing-loop-recursion-time) : 
  [python] [loops] [recursion] [time]
- [Get a time value from a text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584199/get-a-time-value-from-a-text-file-in-java): [java] [time]
- [ruby class undefined method (NoMethodError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47612539/ruby-class-undefined-method-nomethoderror): [ruby] [class] [methods]
- [Python - How to judge if input variable is duplicated in a function or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571842/python-how-to-judge-if-input-variable-is-duplicated-in-a-function-or-not): [python] [function] [class]
- [Removing an imported text file (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613575/removing-an-imported-text-file-python) 
  [python] [string] [file] [kindle]
- [Reading certain number of elements from File in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47578715/reading-certain-number-of-elements-from-file-in-java) 
  [java] [file] [io]
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690406/merging-two-text-files-by-line 
  [file] [text] [merge]

Can you see how the authors just used words from the title without these being valuable as tags to categorize the problem? The tags from my list above do not help categorize, they do not help to filter questions or identify content (beyond what the title says) and they prevent more useful categorization because the authors thought 'three tags should be enough'.
It's only the combination of those concepts that makes sense, and that is what the title does.

### Quality correlations

Another way of analyzing this is to calculate the average vote for questions tagged in a certain way, and/or the average reputation of question authors for tags (assuming high reputation means high skill in selecting useful tags, and only doing this for tags with lots of usages), and/or the average number of answers per tag. I assume these numbers cannot easily be calculated from the REST API of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Tags are used to categorize questions. Answerers use that categorization to find questions to answer, but answerers are not the only users on the site. Other users have other uses for tags and categorization. Supporting tags also help answerers determine if a question is something they might be interested in answering from a glance.

Comment: Same argument, answerers need good tags to judge whether questions are of interest to them. Tags that just repeat the title do not help, they are spam. People seeking answers use google or search for questions, nobody types `[checkbox]` instead of just checkbox in search for a checkbox problem. Tags indeed categorize, that's their strength. The list I showed weakens overall tag quality and thus overall question categorization, same as meta-tags.

Comment: ... You would not put "I have 919 points of reputation on Stack Overflow" on your cv either, so why not remove it altogether?

Comment: Not sure what your point is. My point is that tags should pass questions to expert on a subject, and the given tags cannot do that, because they describe concepts for which being an expert is not possible.

Comment: @tkruse `nobody types [checkbox] instead of just checkbox in search for a checkbox problem` Got a source for that claim? These are not meta tags. [**Meta-tags ... do not describe the content of the question.** They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.).](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). While these are very general tags, [they do not fit any of the criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/288751).

Comment: The proposal here seems like a huge waste of time at best, not to mention a completely unnecessary limitation. If people use the system properly, everyone's questions will be tagged correctly. Now that doesn't always happen, so we have the ability to edit tags. If you see a question with tags that do not describe the content of the questions, remove those tags. If you see a question that is missing an important tag, add it in there. If you run out of space for important tags, sort by importance and pick the top 5. Don't go on a witch hunt after long established tags that aren't causing harm.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Also note I did not ask for burnination, only for "Reduce tags usage", meaning helping users to avoid those tags that wont do them or anyone else any good. In a similar way, some tags already have a description starting with "DO NOT USE" or "AMBIGUOUS"

Comment: Tags get "DO NOT USE" notices when they are in the process of being burninated. Sometimes burninations fall flat on their faces and don't end up going anywhere, and sometimes they succeed, but the tags are later recreated by someone with the privilege and they start getting added to questions again. We don't just tell people to stop using a tag and leave it, that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Good questions will get many reviews and thus will have good tags eventually.

Removing bad tags will not improve bad questions, not even the tagging of bad questions. Bad questions will always flood views and subscriptions.

So overall not worth bothering.